# How does database work for Windows development?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

When developing a windows app how can I know which databases I can use and still allow the app to work on all windows machines?

Does Windows have a native database engine? If I install SQL Server and use it for my app how could the app work on a machine that doesn’t have SQL Server installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a SQL Server Express which is a free version of SQL Server that you would need to package together with your application.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express